# Efficent Way To Search For An Item In A Datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datatable that has 2 fields an example is shown below

```
Field A   Field B
0100      0300
0800      1122
5000      6000
```

These all represent ranges i.e. 0100-0300, I want to select (if any) the row that has an input range within its bounds i.e. if the input range is 0820-0900 then Row 2 would be selected from the table above.

My question is is there any efficent way to do this instead of looking one by one through the datatable until I find a match?

Both parts should be within the defined range.

I have to do this process serval thousand times and the lookup set is small so I put the lookup data in a datatable and want to now query the datable instead of having to call a database several thousands of times. Is this a correct approach or is it better to call the server?

Comment: Why not ask your database server to do it for you?

Comment: have you heard of linq, its a wonderful thing, helps you write SQL like queries although not as powerful but close enough. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: on second thoughts @RowlandShaw is correct, if you can query it, its better.

Comment: @DarthCoder, for the record, linq itself won't write sql statements or connect to a database. You need something like EntityFramework or LinqToSql for that.

Comment: Please explain, both parts should be inside the range defined by FieldA and FieldB? For example `0820 >= FieldA AND 0900 <= FieldB`

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me. Either user DataTable.Select() or user DataTable.AsEnumberable() and a linq query

Comment: Take a look at DataTable.Select - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Rowland Shaw maybe there is no DB Server and he is using DataTables as is data structure

Comment: datatable is a structure that can hold tables right ?? isn't it already out of DB ? I am sorry, I dont think i get the question.

Comment: Or perhaps he has already loaded the data for other purposes and now he needs a subset of the same data. Not really smart to go again to the database.

Comment: This should be reopened, I have already voted to do so.  Please add to it if you can

Comment: @Steve this is exactly the case, I have to do this lookup several thousands of times. I edited the question above

Comment: In your example the fields appear filled with zero to the length of 4 characters. This is always the same? I mean, there is no 12345 for fieldA or 98765 for FieldB?

Comment: @Steve there could be 12345 to 98765

Comment: Then you should change your database to store numeric values not strings with variable length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already loaded your datatable from the database then you could use many ways to filter your values using directly the DataTable already in memory. (Makes no sense in this case to go again to the database)

The DataTable.Select approach is really simple

```
string test = "0820-0900";
string[] parts = test.Split('-');
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("FieldA <= '" + parts[0] + 
                           "' AND FieldB >= '" + parts[1] + "'");
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
    Console.WriteLine(r.Field<string>("FieldA") + "-" + r.Field<string>("FieldB"));
```

The LINQ way

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => string.Compare(x.Field<string>("FieldA"),parts[0]) <= 0 && 
                           string.Compare(x.Field<string>("FieldB"),parts[1]) >= 0).ToList();
```

But all these methods have a problem because the string "1111" is alphabetically lower than the string "3", so, if you have data in your fields with a variable string length you need to add zeros to the beginning of data and to the strings used to check the content of your datatable. This will render the code more complex and at the end of the work very difficult to maintain and test.

The solution is to change your database fields to be numeric and then you could use a simple comparison to extract the values in the range required

```
string test = "0820-0900";
string[] parts = test.Split('-');
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("FieldA <= " + Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]) + 
                           " AND FieldB >= Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
    Console.WriteLine(r.Field<string>("FieldA") + "-" + r.Field<string>("FieldB"));
```

If you don't have the table in memory you could query directly the database with code like this

```
string test = "0820-0900";
string[] parts = test.Split('-');
string cmdText = "select * from table where field <= @p1 AND FieldB >= @p2";
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
    using(SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
  1.  DataRow[] result = table.Select("FieldA >= 100 AND FieldA<= 300");
  2.  // Create a DataView
      DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
      dv.RowFilter = "FieldA >= 100 AND AND FieldA<= 300";
      // dv will now have filtered rows only and you can use it as source
```